# threshold analysis for several images and save results in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, opencv

I would like to perform a threshold analysis for several images, each with different values for the lower threshold limit. I would like to save the results in a csv file. Unfortunately, my code does not work the way I want it to. I am a python beginner.
Thanks for your help!

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

x = []
y = []

Source_Path = 'Images/Image'

with open('Thresh.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(Source_Path)):
      for j in range(100,255):
         ret,thresh = cv.threshold(i,j,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
         count = np.sum(thresh == 255)
         x.append(count)
      y.append(x)
   writer.writerow(y)
```

Comment: I believe you want to write y instead of x:    `writer.writerow(x)` --->  `writer.writerow(y)`

Comment: Yes. But also with writer.writerow(y) it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read the image first before you can threshold it. Start with

```
img = cv.imread("file.jpg") 
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Don't worry about writing the results to a csv file until you have gathered all the statistics that you want in a numpy array. Then write that array to disk using

```
np.savetext("foo.csv", np_array, delimiter=",")
```